# Unity ads - ограничение количества показов

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

В просторах интернета не нашел информации каким образом можно ограничить количество показов в `Unity Ads`.

Допустим 5 раз в сутки, предусмотрена ли эта функция ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, там 25 раз в день можно показывать.

Если вам надо меньше, вы можете хранить информацию о том, сколько раз сегодня показали рекламу в PlayerPrefs. И перед показом рекламы проверять эти данные.